# External SD card now says "SD card blank or has unsupported file system"

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, external-sd

> "External SD card now says "SD card blank or has unsupported file system"

after I attempted to backup on my computer. It is a Samsung Galaxy "Vibrant" running Froyo (2.2) I mounted the card upon plugging into my computer, opened explorer and attempted to copy files for backup. Now I don't see data on my computer, mostly photos and videos I'm concerned with. Can the data on the external SD card be retrieved? If so, how. Thanks!

Comment: Steps for data recovery are described here: [Corrupted 16GB Samsung micro SD card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26819/corrupted-16gb-samsung-micro-sd-card/26820#26820)